# Find two matrices A and B containing at max three zeros each such that rank(A)=rank(B)=rank(AB)=rank(BA)+1=2

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, matrix-equations, matrix-rank

Find two 3x3 matrices A and B each containing at max three zeros that satisfy the condition,
rank($\textbf{A}$)=rank($\textbf{B}$)=rank($\textbf{AB}$)=rank($\textbf{BA}$)+1=2

My attempt:
Let A=[ $a_{1}$ $a_{2}$ $a_{3}$] and B=[$b_{1}$ $b_{2}$ $b_{3}$]

Let {$a_{1}$, $a_{2}$} form a basis for Col A and {$b_{1}$, $b_{2}$} form a basis for Col B.

AB= A [$b_{1}$ $b_{2}$ $b_{3}$] = [A$b_{1}$ A$b_{2}$ A$b_{3}$]

BA =B [$a_{1}$ $a_{2}$ $a_{3}$] = [B$a_{1}$ B$a_{2}$ B$a_{3}$]

We want Rank (AB)=2 and rank (BA)=1, if $b_{3}$ $\in$ Nul A and A$b_{1}$, A$b_{2}$ are two linearly independent vectors, matrix AB satisfy the condition. I don't know how to tackle this question, how should one think? Any help / hints would be appreciated!

Comment: I would suggest that you first ignore the zero-entry constraint, then use the matrices $PAP^{-1},PBP^{-1}$ for a "random" matrix $P$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Have I understood it correctly, that if A and B satisfy the conditions then so will $PAP^{-1}$ and $PBP^{-1}$ because they can be thought of as the same linear transformation but written with respect to another basis?

Comment: That's correct.